# How do I get page numbers to appear on rldc microsoft reports (local mode) when exported to pdf?

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer2008

I need the page numbers to appear on the pdf export of the report. I'm using reportviewer 9. Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 49, accepted):

What you have to do is make a page header, using Report->Page header

Make a text box in it and put this in there 
`=Globals.PageNumber & " of " & Globals.TotalPages`

Comment: Is there a way to get the PageNumber on the body of the report?

Comment: You can also open the Expression panel, where you can see all the possibile values and formulas assignable to the TextBox, by right clicking on the TextBox and selecting Expression...